# Would a dual band router help when on low speed dsl?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I am stuck on 3Mbps dsl and cant upgrade (verizon doesnt have a faster option in mt location).  The current modem/router is a DLink 2750B which is only 2.4ghz.

I also have 2 linksys range extenders to reach the upper floors and balcony area. When 1 hardwired desktop and eve a wireless laptop are on and either uploading or downloading a page, the speed per device drops considerably to almost unusable. And trying to load youtube on a cellphone on wifi is bad--loading every minute or so.

Would a dual band router/modem help distribute the load to somehow make the experience smoother? Or would it still all be bottlenecked by the terrible 3dn/1up dsl speed?

Comment: Since 3Mbps is your max speed, a dual band router won't help much.  I have obtained faster speeds using a dual band router on the 5Ghz frequency, but my max speed is 150Mbps.  Using the 2.4Ghz band does prove to slow down my speed, but I am still able to reach 80Mbps+ on it.  At 3Mbps, the symptoms you are experiencing on your devices are normal.  You will need to upgrade your service if you want any kind of improvement.

Comment: Thanks. I wish i could convince the owner to upgrade but his verizon email is linked to his business email account-and they stopped the domain hosting when leaving verizon. Looks like he/we are stuck with terrible internet

Answer (score 0):

I am using a TP-Link TL-R480T+ Broadband router with load balance.
I use it to split up different computers and services on the two existing internet connections, which clearly eases the load.

What does not work, is to combine the two connections to one, if you use a "point-to-point" connection, like loading web pages or accessing FTP. On the other hand you can combine multi-threaded connections, like torrents.

The broadband router gives the option to choose how computers use the connections and even if they should be combined when accessing a specific port.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Getting a better router/access point setup will help your speed if the issue is with your LAN (and from what you describe it is), but it will not allow you go faster then 3mbps (ie about 300kbyte per second).

Range extenders are generally a bad idea as they greatly reduce the available bandwidth.   The "correct" solution is to cable multiple access points together using ethernet - where this not possible, sometimes you can use Powerline devices to use the power cable to link devices together.

Depending on your house setup, getting 802.11ac stuff (which speaks on the 5 gig band) will help as there is more frequency available and less interference, as well as using smarter technology [beam forming] - of-course, the higher frequency means it will not penetrate walls as well.

I would leave the 2750B plugged in to the network but disable WIFI on it, and get a high quality (ASUS is good) ethernet 802.11n router to act as an access point.   If you can remove one or both repeaters because of the stronger signal strength, even better.